# Animated Mesh Gradient with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, gradient, figma

I want to make a background animated gradient like [this ones protoyped on Figma](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1138140949397225339).

[Picture of Animated Gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3ANv.jpg)

I saw some solutions of animated gradients in CSS like [the one of this page](https://www.gradient-animator.com/), but **it only generates a common linear-gradient and changes the background position**.

What i'm looking for is a **mesh gradient** like the Figma examples (is builted with shapes, a blur layer and some noise) and animate it like the [Figma prototype](https://www.figma.com/proto/kWAty8cksL5VRsY8r2v9go/Animated-gradients-(Community)?page-id=0%3A1&node-id=2%3A194&starting-point-node-id=2%3A194&scaling=min-zoom&show-proto-sidebar=1).

It can be done with pure CSS? or what could be a nice solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You'd definitely need something alongside CSS to animate it like you desire, JS would be a good bet. This is really a project in itself, but take a look at What a Mesh. It does what you're looking for, I don't think it's actually available for public/commercial use, but you might get some inspiration for how to approach it.

https://whatamesh.vercel.app/